# Bypassing functions that do not exist

Tags: dm-script

how would it be possible to bypass functions that are not existing in DM
such that the main code would still run? Try/catch does not seem to work, e..g

```
image doSomething(number a,number b)
{
    try 
    {
    whateverfunction(a,b)
    }
    catch 
    {
    continue
    }
}


number a,b
doSomething(a,b)
```

Also conditioning wont work, e.g..

```
image doSomething(number a,number b)
{

    if(doesfunctionexist("whateverfunction"))
    {
    whateverfunction(a,b)
    }
}


number a,b
doSomething(a,b)
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As "unknown" commands are caught by the script-interpreter, there is no easy way to do this. However, you can construct a workaround by using `ExecuteScriptCommand()`.

There is an example tutorial to be found in this [e-book](http://dmscript.tavernmaker.de/), but in short, you want to do something like the following:

```
String scriptCallStr = "beep();\n"
scriptCallStr = "MyUnsaveFunctionCall();\n"

number exitVal 
Try { exitVal = ExecuteScriptString(scriptCallStr ); }
Catch { exitVal = -1; break; }

if ( -1 == exitVal )
{
    OKDialog("Sorry, couldn't do:\n" + scriptCallStr )
}
else
{
    OKDialog( "All worked. Exit value: " + exitVal )
}
```

This works nicely and easy for simple commands and if your task is only to "verify" that a script could run.

It becomes clumsy, when you need to pass around parameters. But even then there are ways to do so. (The 'outer' script could create an object and pass the object-ID per string. Similarly, the 'inner' script can do the same and return the script-object ID as exit-value.)

Note: You can of course also put `doesfunctionexist` inside the test-script, if you do only want to have a "safe test", but don't actually want to execute the command.

Comment: Thanks alot!
I will try these!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you need there might also be another workaround solution: Wrapper-functions in a library. This can be useful if you want to run the same script on different PCs with some of which having the functionality - most likely some microscope - while others don't. 
You can make your main-script use wrapper methods and then you install different versions of the wrapper method script scripts as libraries.

```
void My_SpecialFunction( )
{
   SpecialFunction()    // use this line on PCs which have the SpecialFunction()
   DoNothing()          // use alternative line on PCs which don't have the SpecialFunction()
}

My_SpecialFunction( )
```

I have used this in the past where the same functionality (-stage movement-) required different commands on different machines.